# Implementação AngularJS consumindo dados providos do Laravel usando CORS

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel, rest, angularjs

Estou tentando criar um *web service* em Laravel 4, que será consumido por um aplicativo mobile usando AngularJS. Quando faço as requisições AJAX com o AngularJS, ele dá erro de Cross Domain por estar em outro domínio. Como resolver?

Comment: Você pode ser mais específico em sua pergunta? O que você está tentando fazer e qual o problema que acontece com CORS?

Comment: A minha idéia é criar um webservice em laravel, e consumir isso em um aplicativo mobile usando angular.
O problema quando faço as requisições ajax com o angular, ele da erro de Cros Domain por estar em outro dominio.

Comment: Incorporei seu comentário à pergunta. Se tiver mais informações a acrescentar, por favor edite a sua pergunta.

Comment: Acho que a pergunta pode ser reaberta. Basicamente ele está fazendo CORS com Laravel e AngularJS, o que pode ser útil pra muita gente.

Comment: @bigown, a pergunta original era "qual a melhor forma de se trabalhar com Laravel e AngularJS", mencionando uma "dificuldade com CORS". Depois que Valmir esclareceu o que estava tentando fazer, a pergunta ficou específica e, a meu ver, válida.

Answer (score 2):

Para ativar CORS (troca de dados entre servidores diferentes usando AJAX), você precisa fazer modificações no seu cliente (AngularJS) e no seu servidor (Laravel).

### Cliente (AngularJS)

No seu controlador AngularJS, altere o atributo `$http.defaults.useXDomain` para `true`. Também pode ser necessário remover o cabeçalho `X-Requested-With`, a depender do servidor. A configuração fica assim:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'myAppApiService']);

myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }
]);
```

(retirado de http://better-inter.net/enabling-cors-in-angular-js/)

A partir daí você pode fazer a requisição normalmente dentro de seu *controller*:

```js
$scope.fazRequisicao = function() {
  $http.get('http://aplicacao.com/servico')
    .success(function(data) {
      alert("OK");
    });
};
```

Por causa dessa configuração, o seu navegador informará ao servidor o domínio de onde a requisição está partindo, através do cabeçalho HTTP `Origin`.

### Servidor (Laravel 4)

Além disso, na aplicação do servidor, você deve adicionar um campo ao cabeçalho das respostas HTTP, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, indicando que domínios podem receber a resposta (ou `*` para qualquer domínio).

Em PHP puro, isso pode ser feito incluindo a seguinte linha no início do código:

```php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Isso afeta todas as respostas HTTP da sua aplicação, permitindo que elas sejam recebidas em qualquer domínio. Essa não é uma boa prática de segurança.

O recomendado é você permitir o acesso a apenas alguns *controllers*. Para isso, nos *controllers* que serão usados pela sua aplicação cliente, use um filtro para adicionar às respostas o cabeçalho `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->afterFilter(function($response)<!-- language: lang-php -->
    {
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        return $response;
    });
}
```

(Fonte: http://acairns.co.uk/2013/01/routing-and-cors-with-laravel-4/)

Answer (score 0):

Um dos melhores posts que vi referente ao Laravel + AngularJS foi este link a seguir:
http://blog.neoxia.com/laravel4-and-angularjs/

Comment: Boa dica, tem muita coisa neste post, obrigado

Comment: Opa, por nada. Eu também estou querendo entrar nesse mundo de SPA's logo logo.